Number of faces in n-dimensional boolean cube
Consider an n-dimensional boolean cube. How many faces of fixed dimension $d$ which intersect the specific $l$-dimensional face does it have?
In other words, here's an example: $n = 3$, $d = 1$, $l = 1$ (dimension $1$ is a line inside a cube). If we fix a line inside a cube, then exactly 5 different lines intersect the fixed one.
My question is: how do I generalise it? I've computed manually all possible cases for $n = 3$, but I don't see a pattern which would help me do it for any $n$. Here are my calculations:
Since for any $l$-dimensional face we need exactly $2^l$ distinct points, this result makes perfect sense:
$l = 0, d = 0: 1\\
l = 1, d = 0: 2\\
l = 2, d = 0: 4\\
l = 3, d = 0: 8$
$l = 0, d = 1: 3\\
l = 1, d = 1: 5\\
l = 2, d = 1: 8\\
l = 3, d = 1: 12
$
$l = 0, d = 2: 3\\
l = 1, d = 2: 4\\
l = 2, d = 2: 5\\
l = 3, d = 2: 6
$
Any face inside a cube can be covered only once by the whole cube, so this also makes perfect sense:
$l = 0, d = 3: 1\\
l = 1, d = 3: 1\\
l = 2, d = 3: 1\\
l = 3, d = 3: 1
$

Apparently, $$\sum_{i=0}^{\min(n-d,l)}\binom{n-l}{n-d-i}\cdot\binom{l}{i}\cdot2^i$$

@IvanNeretin, could you describe the intuition behind the answer or how you found it?

Long story short, what is an $n$-dimensional boolean cube? It is a set $\{0,1\}^n$. Now what is an $l$-dimensional "face"? It is a set of conditions that "fix" $(n-l)$ variables at either $0$ or $1$, while leaving the other $l$ variables "free".
Now comes a $d$-dimensional "face" which "intersects" that. It has $(n-d)$ fixed variables; say, $i$ of those belong to the free variables of the $l$-dimensional thing, of which there are $l$. You may choose which variables these are in $\binom{l}{i}$ ways, and each of them may be fixed either at $0$ or at $1$, hence $2^i$. The remaining $(n-d-i)$ fixed variables of the $d$-dimensional thing correspond to the fixed variables of the $l$-dimensional thing, hence $\binom{n-l}{n-d-i}$. (No power of $2$ here, as they have no choice where to get fixed.)
As for the limits of the summation, they don't matter much if we follow the common convention that binomials outside of the Pascal triangle are all $0$.
All in all, we get
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n-l}{n-d-i}\cdot\binom{l}{i}\cdot2^i$$
So it goes.
